# How to convert a datetime string to a string of format syntax in python

Tags: python, datetime, format

I have already known that `dateutil.parser.parse` can parse most known datetime formats string to datetime object.

Now I'm wondering is there a method can tell me the format of a datetime string.

For example:

given `"2001-01-08 01:01:01"`, return its format like `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

```
>>> get_time_str_format("2001-01-08 01:01:01")
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Why do you think that in `2001-01-08 01:01:01` Python recognizes which is a day and which is a month?

Comment: You can roll your own, but it cannot possibly be done with complete accuracy. If given a datetime with no context, how would you determine if the hours 10,11, or 12 are on a 24-hour clock (%H) or a 12-hour clock (%I)? Are you guaranteed that a 12-hour clock would always have AM/PM? Would you assume that if it doesnt', it is a 12-hour clock?

I guess you could return both possibilities depending on your requirements. It would be problematic if your goal is to extract the format from an example time and then apply it to other times.

Comment: MarianD and David Jenkins Thank you. So the problem is how to determine what the time really is without context. Tools like dateutil that parse datetime string just give suggest results. It's not accurate. I think the only way to do it is limited format styles that with no ambiguity.